# tel: link doesn't work in an overlay div (?)

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple code I'm working on

and today I've discovered something singular.

The same code

```
<a href="tel:+393481234567">348-1234567</a>
```

it is pasted three times in that page
- it is pasted in a visible div, there it works and clicking the link, the call starts,

- it is pasted into the navigation menu, which actually is an overlay DIV that later a jquery function will unhide. Well in that overlay, the same link doesn't "call".

Do you have any clue of this?

To check it in action see this test page with a smartphone
http://hc.no-ip.biz/nav/tel-doesnt-work.html

the number is available in the loremipsum text below the top orange bar and there **it works** (call happen), while if you click the hamburger button to unhide the navigation menu, you find that again the same phone link twice,
either as li item as an link at the very bottom of the navigation menu.

If you check that page source, you'll see that the link has been copied and pasted, no differences.

EDIT 01:
as suggested by Florian I've changed the structure
added an id="hamburger" to the div with menu button
changed the javascript to

```
$('#hamburger').on('click',function(){
```

but behaves the same :-(

EDIT 02:
solved, thank you to Florianb for his interesting link. Two more "click" events (they were optional) were intercepting the click event when the overlay was un-hide. I've removed them and now it works properly.

EDIT 03:
for the convenience of everybody, here you the code of the page WITH the issue, at bottom the code with the two events , removed.

```
    <header class="fissotop">
    <div id="responsive-logos">
        <div id="responsive-logo1" class="logo"><a href="#">
        <img class="btn-open" src="recupero-euro-logo.png" alt="">
        <img class="btn-close" src="recupero-euro-logo.png" alt=""></a></div>
        <div id="responsive-logo2" class="logo"><a href="#">
        <img class="btn-open" src="recupero-euro-logo-32.png" alt="">
        <img class="btn-close" src="recupero-euro-logo-32.png" alt=""></a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="navigation-brief">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">RecuperoEuro</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Chiavette</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Schede</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SSD</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contatti</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="button" id="hamburger">
            <img class="btn-open" src="hamburger-button-32-w.png" alt="">
            <img class="btn-close" src="close-button-32-w.png" alt=""></div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>

<div class="navigation-full">
    <div class="wrap">
        <nav>
            <ul class="wrap-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Recupero Euro</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Processo</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Condizioni</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dove siamo</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Chiavette</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Kingston</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sandisk</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Verbatim</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Transcend</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lexar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Altre</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">SSD e Schede</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">SSD Solid State Drive</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Compact Flash CF</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">MicroSD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Monolitiche</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contatti</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://tickets/newticket.php?department=4">Creare un ticket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="tel:+393481234567">348-1234567</a></li>
                        <li>info{at]mail.it</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="social">
            <a href="tel:+393481234567">348-1234567</a> lorem ipsum
face-boken twittagain
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="marginetop">
<a href="tel:+393481234567">348-1234567</a> Longnose lancetfish, goldfish clingfish Mex
ican golden trout bluntnose minnow; lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn-close').fadeOut(200);
    var open = false;
    $('#hamburger').on('click',function(){
     if(open == false){
        $('.navigation-full, .btn-close').fadeIn(200);
        $('#navigation-brief ul li, .btn-open').fadeOut(200);
        open = true;
     } else {
        $('.navigation-full, .btn-close').fadeOut(200)
        $('#navigation-brief ul li, .btn-open').fadeIn(200);
        open = false;
     }
    });
    $('.navigation-full').on('click', function(){
        $('.navigation-full, .btn-close').fadeOut(200);
        $('#navigation-brief ul li, .btn-open').fadeIn(200);
        open = false;
    });
    $('.wrap').on('click', function(){
        return false;
    });
})
 </script>
```

after Florian's suggestion, I've removed the last two selectors in the javascript since they were covering a too wide portion of the page in the interested area with the issue, as hinted, they were intercepting the clicking action, so the following code has been removed

```
    $('.navigation-full').on('click', function(){
        $('.navigation-full, .btn-close').fadeOut(200);
        $('#navigation-brief ul li, .btn-open').fadeIn(200);
        open = false;
    });
    $('.wrap').on('click', function(){
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: I've read it twice - still makes no sense at all to me.

Comment: hello, it is easier to try it, the code in the html page is the same, it is present as link at the begin of the first p, there it works. While if you click the hamburger/menu button, in the overlay that appears, it is listed the same phone number link but it doesn't work.

Comment: Look at lines 147 through 149 of your HTML. You have an `click` event handler that eats the event.

Comment: wow, but why it works in the p ? Thank you for the hint.

Comment: I have edited my question with latest selector change, no way either targeting the click event to a specific id

Comment: @Robert: to improve your question, put the code-samples into the question, for the case your link won't show that behavior anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You registered a on-click-handler in your script as follows:

```
$('.button a').on('click',function(){...
```

jQuery adopted the [CSS-selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html) as instrument to define the affected DOM-Elements.

Let's see what you have selected:

```
.button a
```

There are two rules hitting your expression.

1. The identifiers: the `.button`-identifier is matched as every **class** of the type button and the `a`-identifier is matched as every **element** of the type anchor.
2. The precedence: by writing `.button a` you tell jQuery to match to every DOM-structure where an element of `.button` is descended by an `a`-element.

So the `a`-element on your main-page misses that constellation whereas it's not matched and no click-handler is attached.

#### You have two options to solve this:

1. Modify the structure of your page or change the selector to become more precise.
2. Trigger the click-event on your own, as it is described at the jQuery-Documents for "[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)" and "[trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)"

*P.s.: This very nice Post [The 30 CSS Selectors you Must Memorize](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048) my help you to get familiar with css-selectors.*

Comment: Hello Florian, but why it works in the visible div? Thank you for the hint :-) . Do you think is it possible to better target the on-click-handler?

Comment: I've given an id="button" to the div with the hamburger button an changed the javascript to "$('#button').on('click',function(){" but it behaves the same... Any kind hint?